# SAS Progam Editor on Unix

Tags: sas

Is there a way to autoindent or a shortcut to insert a select number of spaces as a tab in the SAS Progam Editor on Unix?

I'm used to using the enhanced editor on PC and this is the only part of the switch that I can't find the answer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the line numbers to the left of the code in the program editor, enter the `>>#` command (replace # with a number) to indent '#' spaces to the right and `<<#` for shifting to the left.  Enter these commands on the starting line and ending line.  All rows inclusive between them will shift.

For a single line, `>#` or `<#`.

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to start a flame-war... have you and your team considered NOT using the tab key in code?  This way code always appears consistent regardless of editor/tab settings.  Especially handy when you use a combination of vi/EG/SAS editor/notepad etc... I've worked at places that do this and it works great once you get everyone to agree to it.

When you open up existing code with tabs, just figure out how many spaces the tab is supposed to represent and do a search/replace.

It's still as fast to navigate quickly when you use, ctrl-left/ctrl-right in windows editors (and unix eds if setup that way), or 'w' and 'b' to jump to the next/previous word when using vi.

Cheers
Rob

Comment: Everything is Unix based and run off of the server so we're pretty much stuck with the built-in editor.   Since it doesn't support the tab key, the answer above works well.